# Libav hls parse manifest to get access to variants

Tags: parsing, http-live-streaming, libav, libavformat

It is possible to parse master playlist to get and store all the url’s associated with the variants, using libav, to make downloads according to the variant of my choice. Thanks, all help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

In case that someone else need this information, i found it, you just need to do this in your program:

```
AVFormatContext *fmtctx = NULL;
HLSContext *c = fmtctx -> priv_data;
```

previously you need to add every structure used in "hls.c" (HLSContext, variant, playlist, rendition, etc)

then you can get access to the variant and his associate data (url, bitrate,etc);

```
int a;
for(a=0; a < c->n_variants; a++){
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "url = %s \n", c->playlists[a]->url);
} /*for printing url's of the master playlist*//
```